# Insert a table inside another with one field different

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am trying to copy one table to another in oracle changing the value of one of the fields.

Lets say Tables Original and Temp, so I normally would use this SQL bellow:

```
Insert into Original Select * from Temp where site = 1
```

The problem is that now my Original table already has the site 1 so I need to copy the content of site one to the original table changing site 1 for site 2. I normally would do

```
Insert into Original (site, field1, field2, field3) Select '2', field1, field2, field3 from Temp where site = 1
```

However I have few hundre tables to do that and I am looking for a solution where I don't need to enter the name of the fields in each statement.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you want the `merge` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - how would that eliminate the need to specify the field names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote simple PLSQL procedure, code below. It generates insert string to output, 
if these suits you, you can copy/paste them and run manually or you can uncomment 
line near end and inserts will be done automatically. Tested on sample data, worked fine.

Procedure operates on columns found in `user_tab_columns`. At first you have to define list of tables which interests you in declare section.
You may want to change some code according to your needs.

Output generated:

```
insert into original (site, F1, F2, F3) select 1, F1, F2, F3 
  from TEMP1 where site = 1
insert into original (site, F2, F1, F3) select 2, F2, F1, F3 
  from TEMP2 where site = 1
insert into original (site, F3, F2, F1) select 3, F3, F2, F1 
  from TEMP3 where site = 1
```

Procedure code:

```
create or replace procedure justdoit is
  type t_var is table of varchar2(30);
  -- table names in uppercase
  tabs t_var := t_var('TEMP1', 'TEMP2', 'TEMP3'); 
  v_sql1 varchar2(4000);
  v_sql2 varchar2(4000);
begin

for i in 1..tabs.count
loop
  v_sql1 := 'insert into original (site, ';
  v_sql2 :=  'select '||i||', ';
  for o in (
    select * from user_tab_columns 
      where table_name = tabs(i)
      order by column_id)
  loop
    if o.column_name <> 'SITE' then
      v_sql1 := v_sql1 || o.column_name||', ';
      v_sql2 := v_sql2 || o.column_name||', ';
    end if;
  end loop;
  v_sql1 := rtrim(v_sql1, ', ')||') '||rtrim(v_sql2, ', ');
  v_sql1 := v_sql1||' from '||tabs(i)||' where site = 1';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql1);
  -- execute immediate v_sql1;  -- <- uncomment this line
end loop;

end justdoit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query

```
INSERT INTO Original select '2' from Temp union all select * from Temp where site=1;
```

Explanation :

I) value '2' will be inserted into first column named "site"

II)Column values field1,field2,field3 from Temp table will be insserted to field1,field2,field3 of original table

Comment: Yes I know that work (I even put in the description) but I am trying to not to use the fields name as I have to repeat this to many different table with many fields. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you expecting query which should not mention field names in subquery also ? @IcaroNZ

Comment: I hope the above edited answer will suits your requirement .. check it out @lcaroNZ

Comment: As I imagine now I have a mismatch in the numbers of fields from each side Original table has all fields and the select state has all fields plus the 'static' one.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `create table as select (ctas)` query with the new value you want for the site column, but specify a temporary column name. Then after table creation, drop the 'bad' site column, and rename the temporary one to site (3 statements involved per table), like this:

```
create table original as
select '2' as new_site, t.* from temp t where site = 1;

alter table original drop column site;

alter table original rename column new_site to site;
```

Note that if you've currently only truncated these 'original' tables, drop them before running the CTAS queries off of your temp tables.

Comment: Yes I told about it too, but as I describe I have to do it to many, many tables, I was hoping for something easier and faster. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: This doesn't involve specifying the column names, which is what you described. With a list of tables you could generate these 3 statements in an excel formula and just drag it down rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use another temp table

insert into temp2
 select * from temp1 where 
 site=1;
 update temp2 set site=2 
  where site=1;

insert into maintable
 select * from temp2 where site=2;

Delete from temp2 where site=2;